# what files/folders should I delete to reduce project size in order to share it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter project and as I noticed, it has a giant size, And I know that what cayuse is files/folders that can easily build and the files of packages.

as of now, I deleted the `build` folder and I want to know which other files should be deleted that I miss, And what files I shouldn't delete besides the lib folder.

Comment: I would just share it on github. Github ignores all the generated files by default.

Comment: do 'flutter clean', and after that did 'flutter pub get', for the folder you have in you pc is surely large. but when you debug it. the app that been compile will be in smaller size when installed to your emulator/device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command "flutter clean" should delete all unnecessary directories that are not needed for publishing. You can look it up for more information